# Getting "Default activity not found" even though setting correct intent filters

Tags: android

I'm trying to change my default activity in Android Studio. I have added the MAIN and LAUNCHER intent tags to VrMainActivity, removed the MAIN and LAUNCHER tags from MainActivity and still get a "Default Activity not found" error. I have also invalidated cache/restarted. Also no errors in the Merged Manifest section of the editor, totally stuck on what the problem is.

Here's my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.thanics.andrew.halocontrol">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.vr.headtracking"
        android:required="false"
        android:version="1" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.vr.mode"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.vr.high_performance"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Make accelerometer and gyroscope hard requirements for good head tracking. -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/halo_drone_app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/halo_drone_app_icon_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".VrMainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="density|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
            android:enableVrMode="@string/gvr_vr_mode_component"
            android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:theme="@style/VrActivityTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <!--<category android:name="com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD" />-->
                <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.DAYDREAM" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- The VR icon to be used in Daydream Home comes in two parts:
            a foreground icon and a background icon.  -->
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.vr.icon"
                android:resource="@mipmap/halo_drone_app_icon" />
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.vr.icon_background"
                android:resource="@mipmap/halo_drone_app_icon" />

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StereoFlightActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you need to use `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` to make any
>   activity as launcher .

Just replace `<category android:name="com.google.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` to `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` inside your Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

in the `<intent-filter>` tag